# Pupeteer: override document property

Tags: javascript, automation

I want to override the `document.createElement` property on Pupeteer.

I tried this on evaluate:

```
await page.evaluate(() => {
    const originalCreateElement = document.createElement;
    Object.defineProperty(document, 'createElement', {
        value: function (tagName) {
            var element = originalCreateElement.call(document, tagName);
            [...]
            return element
        },
    });
});
```

But I got this error: `Uncaught Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot redefine property: createElement`.

Is it possible to override this kind of properties with Pupeteer?